# Terraform EKS specify node-role.kubernetes.io label on node group

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

In the terraform `aws_eks_node_group` resource I can't set :

```
labels = {
  "node-role.kubernetes.io/others" = "other"
}
```

as AWS complains labels key should not contains kubernetes.io.

```
Error: error creating EKS Node Group (my-cluster:others): InvalidParameterException: Label cannot contain reserved labels kubernetes.io/
{
  ClusterName: "my-cluster",
  Message_: "Label cannot contain reserved labels kubernetes.io/",
  NodegroupName: "others"
}
```

Also, EC2 instances spawned have no name and I have no clue on how to specify a Name for my instances based on their node group.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you get a specific error when you set the label as that? And your second question should be a separate question normally but in this case would be a duplicate of [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004229/define-node-names-from-node-groups).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thank you for the answer, updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @hajj nope unfortunately I ended up keeping the default names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) you can't use specific labels, regarding labels:

> The kubernetes.io/ and k8s.io/ prefixes are reserved for Kubernetes core components. Valid label values must be 63 characters or less and must be empty or begin and end with an alphanumeric character ([a-z0-9A-Z]) with dashes (-), underscores (_), dots (.), and alphanumerics between.

Regarding your specific label. There are many issues since k8s 1.15 or 1.16 where some change in the core kubernetes don’t allow that label. [one detailed issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/84912)

As for naming of EC2 instances created by EKS Node Group. Currently, there is no way to pass "Name" tag. This question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902283/adding-name-to-ec2-instances-when-deploying-awseksnodegroup-in-cloudformatio/59920928#59920928) where you can also find the answer how to name your instances for time being.

Answer (score 0):

node-role.kubernetes.io and kubernetes.io - this is DIFFERENT prefixes

Comment: Is this a comment on some post or comment which states they are identical? If so, which one? In any case, this does not really look like an answer to the question; at least not according to [answer]. Can you make more obvious how this is supposed to answer the question?