# Add roles to EKS nodes using Terraform and node groups

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm using Terraform to create an EKS cluster using this [repo](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/tree/master/examples/eks-getting-started) the official hashicorp repo. It works fine but all the nodes have the  role **none**

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
xxxx1.compute.internal                       Ready    **<none>**   3m35s   v1.14.9-eks-658790
xxxx2.compute.internal                       Ready    **<none>**   3m42s   v1.14.9-eks-658790
```

I tried to use labels on the eks node group declaration but it's doesn't work

```
labels           = {"node-role.kubernetes.io/workers5" = "label1"}

Error: error updating EKS Node Group (clustertest:workers5) config: InvalidParameterException: Label cannot contain reserved labels kubernetes.io/
```

Any Idea how can i fix it ? or if there is any work around?

thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you want to set the node role?

Comment: usef for nodeSelector for example

Comment: and for nodeAffinity also

Comment: You can maybe use another label, then? `node-role.kubernetes.io` has special semantics, and nodes (i.e. the `kubelet`) aren't allowed to set it for themselves. [This issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75457) has some insights into the reasons behind that decision (TL;DR: because security).

Answer (score -1):

As already explained by BogdanL and in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/):

> The kubernetes.io/ and k8s.io/ prefixes are reserved for Kubernetes
> core components. Valid label values must be 63 characters or less and
> must be empty or begin and end with an alphanumeric character
> ([a-z0-9A-Z]) with dashes (-), underscores (_), dots (.), and
> alphanumerics between.

So you have to [change this label.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902283/adding-name-to-ec2-instances-when-deploying-awseksnodegroup-in-cloudformatio/59920928#59920928)